# How to debug one-way workflow service with VS 2010?

Tags: .net, wcf, workflow-foundation-4

I'm developing a WWF 4 Service with Visual Studio 2010 and I'm not able to hint on the ReceiveRequest activity where I set a breakpoint.

I set up a one way service deleting SendResponse activity.

Have you any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In this link is the answer to your problems. Ron Jacobs (thanks @RonJacobs!) is the program manager for WF and by downloading the Microsoft.Activities extensions from NuGet and a few Web.config changes you'll see more information about your WF workflows than you thought possible. If you have any problems getting it going let me know.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/12/16/troubleshooting-workflow-services-with-diagnostic-logging.aspx